# NO_APPLICABLE_PROCESS while submitting approval for time sheet entry

Tags: approval-process, field-service-lightning, fieldservice

I have an approval process for timesheet entry:

[image]

I have a timesheet entry which is fulfilling criteria for the approval process.

The approval process is in *active* state.

I am doing something like below in trigger for **TimesheetEntry**:

```
List<Approval.ProcessResult> result = Approval.process(requestList);
```

Getting the below error while submitting the timesheet entry for approval:

```
System.DmlException: Process failed. First exception on row 0; first error: NO_APPLICABLE_PROCESS, No applicable approval process was found.: []:
```

I tried to query the **TimesheetEntry** using the approval process criteria, Able to see my **TimesheetEntry**(Subject of this entry is 1):

[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: I suggest you execute the equivalent SOQL query in the Developer Console to confirm or disprove that the entry criteria do match.

Comment: @rahulgawale The error is same but the situation is changed. My approval process is active and the timesheet entry meets the criteria.

Comment: @KeithC Updated the question with SOQL result. I am able to get the same timesheet entry.